# Spring integration / GCP PubSub : channel subscriber lost

Tags: spring, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

Everything is mostly in the title.
I have a specific channel to send data to PubSub, using Spring integration and this [information about GCP PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring?authuser=1#publishing-messages-using-channel-adapters)

I don't have any problem locally, or on the QA env.
But, in the prod, I have the following error :

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 
'pubSubFlow.channel#1'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The [bean 
'pubSubFlow.channel#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [fr/auchan/lark/tracking/api/v1
/pubsub/PubSubRequestIntegration.class]'; from source: 'bean method pubSubFlow'] doesn't 
have subscribers to accept messages

org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:167) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:600) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.lambda$subscribeTo$2(FluxMessageChannel.java:83) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.3.13.RELEASE.jar:3.3.13.RELEASE]
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:439) ~[reactor-core-3.3.13.RELEASE.jar:3.3.13.RELEASE]
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:526) ~[reactor-core-3.3.13.RELEASE.jar:3.3.13.RELEASE]
reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.3.13.RELEASE.jar:3.3.13.RELEASE]
reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.3.13.RELEASE.jar:3.3.13.RELEASE]
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The [bean 'pubSubFlow.channel#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [PubSubRequestIntegration.class]'; from source: 'bean method pubSubFlow'] doesn't have subscribers to accept messages
org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:61) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
 12 common frames omitted
```

Below is my channel declaration, and the use of ServiceActivator as written is the PubSub Guidelines (see the link above).

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel dataChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()).get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel pubSubChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pubSubFlow(
        MessageChannel dataChannel,
        MessageChannel pubSubChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(dataChannel)
            .fluxTransform(this::toPubSubFormat)
            .channel(pubSubChannel)
            .get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubChannel")
public PubSubMessageHandler sendToPubSub(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
    PubSubMessageHandler adapter = new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate,
            pubSubIntegrationProperties.getTopic());

    adapter.setPublishCallback(
            new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                    log.warn("There was the following error sending the message. " + throwable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    log.debug("Message was sent via the outbound channel adapter to {} : {}", pubSubIntegrationProperties.getTopic(), result);
                }
            });
    return adapter;
}
```

Did I miss something? Why is the pubSubChannel marked as having no subscribers?
Thanks for the help

Comment: It's not about `pubSubChannel`. The `fluxTransform()` creates a `FluxMessageChannel` in a couple places. It would be great to see more stack trace from you...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ArtemBilan . I added more stacktrace, the most I could for now. Hope it help

Comment: What is that `dataChannel`? Can it be made as `FluxMessageChannel`? Is there a possibility to upgrade to the latest Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn ? Can you rethink the logic to not use that `fluxTransform()`? I kinda suggest you some choice since I can't answer what is wrong. There indeed was a race condition in some Spring Integration version for that `FluxMessageChannel`; and I believe that your `dataChannel` has content slightly too early to be processed. That's why you don't see it as a permanent failure.

Comment: All my channels are declared as MessageChannel (I put the information in the post).